# what is scene in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx-2

I recently start learning JavaFX using some tutorials. Actully I was not able to understand the function of scene in detail. I search for more tutorials, but they didn't gave me what I expected. please tell me what is a scene in JavaFX? What is the use of it? I want a detailed answer please.

Comment: Maybe this description of a [class hierarchy for JavaFX](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3529396) might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scene is a class on JavaFX. This class is simply where you usually put your buttons, combo boxes, text fields, and labels.

If you know "web pages", you can think of Scene as something like a "web page". For every page, you are able to view different contents. As for every JavaFX Scene, you are able to view different contents.

If you watch movies, you can think of the Scene class as something like a movie scene. In a movie scene, you view different characters and actions happen. Just like in JavaFX, Scenes give you a place to set up your other JavaFX components like button, etc.

Comment: Is this similar to JFrame in JavaSE?

Comment: Yes, Scene is similar to JFrame in the sense that they can both contain UI components.